# JQuery Issue - Not Working!

Tags: jquery, html

Ok, I've got this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
        <script type="text/javascript" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <title>JQuery Demo 1</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #box
            {
                background-color: #ff0000;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('a').click(function()
                {
                    $('#box').fadeOut();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box">Yes!</div>
        <a href="#">Click me!</a>   
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm following this from the video tutorial series here.  It's the first one in the series. (http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/)

When I execute this, Firebug says error

> $ is not defined [Break On This Error]
>   $(function(){

In the tut, it works ok.  Any help, appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change href to src in your jquery script tag (line 4)...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not necessarily, simple mistake! Check out http://validator.w3.org/ to help you find markup issues. Also I'd look at getting a decent IDE that can point this kind of stuff out. Check out netbeans (http://netbeans.org/)

Comment: I"m just starting out with learning JS, and using Aptana Studion 2.